# For Dropdown to not showing when on Mobile devices

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I tried the code it worked perfect but as per beauty and responsiveness is concern when on mobile devices and on normal Laptop view the dropdown not looks suitable. Is it possible through jQuery to make the dropdown not to show or display when shift to mobile devices and only to display on 4k Screens, PC Desktop Computers, Large Laptops and Tablets and not to be shown on normal small laptops and Mobile devices.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').click(function(){
     var value = $(this).text();
     console.log(value)
     // Update the value and show it to the user
     $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-toggle").html(value);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Search Box With Dropdown List</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-dark d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="search-box mt-3">
        <form action="">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">All</button>
              <div style="z-index: 0;" class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 5</a>

                <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other Options</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light" aria-label="Search input with dropdown button">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why not use `display: none` for `input-group-prepend` in media query?

Comment: you dont need JS for it just CSS and use media queries like this: `@media only screen and (max-width: 3839px) { .input-group-prepend { display: none; } }` But your idea to show only on 4k screens will limit it to evry few screens. No mobile device has a 4K screen and only few laptops or PC user use one.

Comment: @OmerFarooqButt, glad to help